# How to inject a context-aware common state into Quarkus Qute template?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

I am building a "classic" web application with Quarkus with server-side template rendering and form-auth login. I am using quarkus-resteasy-reactive, quarkus-security-jpa, quarkus-resteasy-reactive-qute. It all works fine so far, but I want to the use the current user object in the templates without injecting the SecurityContext into every route and pass it to every template. I noticed there is a concept of [GlobalVariables](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#global_variables), but they are all static and not aware of the context. In other words: One would be the best way in Quarkus to inject a common context into Qute templates?
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at Quarkus Renarde: https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-renarde/dev/index.html#_security

Comment: Thanks! That looks very interesting. I took a close look into the code of Renarde and I noticed my problem seems to solved and I could inject the user object into the tmeplates with inject:user. However, I am very much interested in learning Quarkus and could not find a named Bean "user". How and where is this Bean generated?

Comment: Renarde does that. Read the page about ‘Security’.

Comment: I know, that it does that. I am interested in the "how". How does it do it? Where is the Bean generated. I screened the entire code, but could not figure it out myself. But I am not a DI expert.